# FB.login() in Android native browser doesn't send response on back button click

Tags: android, jquery, facebook, user-interface, popup

We put Facebook login button on our website. We used FB.login() for it. Everything works fine on desktop and in chrome browser for mobile, but when user click on phone back button in facebook login dialog, response doesn't come to our website back.
Facebook login we implemented following way https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/
**Steps to Reproduce:**
  1. Put login button on website using FB.login().
2. User open website on Android native browser.
3. User clicks on this login button. The browser opens a popup with facebook login dialog as a new tab. 
4. User clicks on back button on the phone.
**Expected Behavior:**   A tab with facebook login will be closed and response comes to FB.login(), so we can react on it.
**Actual Behavior:** A tab with facebook login is closed and response doesn't come to FB.login()